# Rails Strip access and display account information

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails)

I have completed that tutorial now i want to display account information of the user Dont't how have any idea.User information like **credit card number and bank name**

[charges_Controller]

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController


    def new
    end

    def create
  # Amount in cents
  @amount = 500

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]

  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )
 @token = Stripe::Token.retrieve(params[:stripeToken])
        puts "hhhhhhhhhh#{@token.id}"
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end
end
```

[charges/new.html.erb]

```
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="A month's subscription"
          data-amount="500"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

[stripe.rb]

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user enters their credit card details into a Stripe-enabled form, the sensitive information is sent to Stripe's servers over a secure HTTPS connection and then Stripe will send you a string identifier for a `Token` object. This token object is then used to create charges against the card represented by the token.

In your controller code you can create an object representing the Stripe Token with:

```
token = Stripe::Token.retrieve(params[:stripeToken])
```

And you can inspect what kind of information is available to you.

See https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#tokens for the full rundown of information available to you in the `Token` object.

But if you examine the object you will find that it only has card data. A Stripe Token can be used for either representing a credit card to charge or a bank account to send a payment to. Therefore, since the token in your example represents a credit card to charge, there will be no bank account information for you to retrieve.

Neither will you have access to the entire credit card number used, because once again, the point of Stripe's API is to relieve you from having to handle storage of secure personal information like that. So for security purposes you won't receive that information.

However, both the `Token` object and the `Charge` object will have a field called `last4` that represents the last four digits of the card number that you may store to help identify the card. You will also have access to brand of card used in the `brand` field.

Example rails console inspection:

```
>token["card"]["last4"]
"4242"
>token["card"]["brand"]
"Visa"
```

Comment: I have added the token code in my charges controller new action and trying to see what value was inside that token on console it is giving me an error Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe::Token instance has invalid ID: nil

Comment: In your original code on line 10 you were using `params[:stripeToken]`. Was `source` getting assigned `nil` this whole time?

Comment: It is not assign nil

Comment: Can you update your code to reflect where you are attempting to create the token object?

Comment: i have updated my code and now i am getting hash ..how to fetch information from that?

Comment: In the code you posted if you wanted a specific value would be `@token["card"]["last4"]`, or if you want to inspect the entire object in your console, adding after the token creation `logger.info @token.inspect`